# `write_formula` in `xlsxwriter` in Python

Tags: python, excel-formula, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am using `xlsxwriter` in Python to create an Excel xlsx.

Consider the code

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

data = (['Average Start Date','365'],['AAA','2'])

worksheet.add_table(1, 1, 4,4, {'data':data,'first_column':True,'style':'Table Style Light 1','autofilter': False,'columns':[{'header':'Attribute'},{'header':'Value'}]})


ws.write_formula('A4', '=IF(A3>1,"Yes", "No")')
ws.write_formula('A5', '=VLOOKUP("Average Start Date",Table1,2,FALSE)/365')
```

After opening the xlsx file with Excel the cell `A4` displays `No`, the formula gets computed. On the other hand the cell `A5` shows `#NAME?`.

If I select the cell `A5`, press F2, which is for editing the formula, and press Enter without apparently modifying anything the formula in `A5` gets computed.

Why is this?
Is there an error in the way I am adding the formula to `A5`?
Is there a way to make that formula get computed automatically?

Comment: What code creates `Table4`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I added a couple of lines to generated the table. I had only included part of the code. I changed `Table4` to `Table1` such that I don't have to write 4 tables, like in my actual code.

Comment: Maybe try to add an explicit name when you create the table, either as part of `add_table` and/or just directly. My guess is that the first time you open the file it is sort of a race condition whereby the Excel calculation engine tries to evaluate `A5` *before* it has created the default name for the table. Perhaps if you explicitly name it first it would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an XlsxWriter error, it is an Excel error. You would get the same result if you entered the formula manually and hit return.

The `#NAME?` error is caused by the fact that the formula refers to a data range called `Table4` which doesn't exist.

Also, you have a syntax error in your code snippet. It should be:

```
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

# Or just
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
```

Also, you should add `wb.close()` to the end of the program.

**[Edit] Answer in the comment by this answer's author**

It looks like Table1 needs to be written as `Table1[]` in the formula, like this: `=VLOOKUP("Average Start Date",Table1[],2,FALSE)/365')`. It will be displayed as `Table1`

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the code. I only writing part of it and I wrote it by memory. In the code there are 4 tables and they are created before the `write_formula` commands. The interesting thing is that the error *doesn't occur* when I enter the formula manually and hit return. Actually, even less makes it work. I open the document generated by the code, select the cell that contains the faulty formula, click on the formula bar, and hit enter, and then it computes.

Comment: It is like if there are hidden characters that prevent the formula being written correctly in the code and then when I select the formula bar they disappear. I really don't know.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thank you for creating XlsxWriter. I just discovered it recently despite being a long-time VBA programmer who has been getting into Python more recently. I am looking forward to blending Python and Excel more in the future.

Comment: It looks like `Table1` needs to be written as `Table1[]` in the formula, like this: `'=VLOOKUP("Average Start Date",Table1[],2,FALSE)/365')`. It will be displayed as `Table1`.

Comment: @jmcnamara Interesting. Now it works! Thank you. How did you notice that? Excel seems to work well with `Table1` when one inputs the formula by hand.